# TypeError: int() argument must be a string in tensorflow

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, object-detection

I had trained a model and generated its inference graph. when i tried to test it on a single image this error appeared to me

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\tensorflow1\models\research\object_detection\Object_detection_image.py",
> line 98, in <module>
>     feed_dict={image_tensor: image_expanded})   File "C:\Users\Hamada Fathy\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py",
> line 877, in run
>     run_metadata_ptr)   File "C:\Users\Hamada Fathy\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py",
> line 1069, in _run
>     np_val = np.asarray(subfeed_val, dtype=subfeed_dtype)   File "C:\Users\Hamada
> Fathy\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py",
> line 492, in asarray
>     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order) TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not
> 'NoneType'
```

Comment: Hi Please refer this page for asking good question which usually get upvoted,which helps in getting good answer [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: After follow the advice of @v8-E , could you share the code where you get this error?